# How to convert a string to Date class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, date

```
var from = "2012-01-13 T11:00:00";

Date date = parseDate(from);
```

How can I convert this text to a Date object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ezineasp.net/Samples/Javascript/Date-Object/Convert-String-to-Date/Default.aspx) article, you can use different date patterns:

```
MM/dd/yyyy
yyyy/MM/dd
MM-dd-yyyy
MMMM dd, yyyy
MMM dd, yyyy
```

and date-time patterns:

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

In your case the simplest thing to do (maybe) is to remove the `T` character and replace `-` separators with `/`:

```
function parseDate(from){
    from = from.replace('T', '').replace(/-/g,'/');
    return new Date(from);
}
```

Comment: Ahah, slashes... might you know which browsers this works on?

Comment: Do you know if it's in the standard?

Comment: not `replace`; if `Date('yyyy/mm/dd etc')` is in the standard

Comment: It is so. [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) page 169

Comment: Actually page 171 says "*2. If Type(v) is String, then 
a. Parse v as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse method (15.9.4.2); let V be the time 
value for this date.*" According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse this means that it is only valid to parse RFC2822 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14 or ISO 8601 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 date formats. I am thus suspicious of which format (if either) `yyyy/mm/dd` belongs to. That said, your method works for me just fine. =)

Comment: All right. I didn't understand your question was related to that specific format: I thought you was talkin about `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your string manually and then use the constructors in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

However, see [javascript - string to date - php iso string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450837/javascript-string-to-date-php-iso-string-format)

According to the ECMAScript 5 specification (p171):

```
15.9.3.2  new Date (value)

[...]
If Type(v) is String, then [...] Parse v as a date, in exactly 
the same manner as for the parse method (15.9.4.2); let V be the 
time value for this date.
```

And according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse the functions accepts only [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) or [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date formats. This means that you are allowed to do `new Date(YOUR_FORMAT_STRING)` but it is only valid if your dates are that format.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [JavaScript Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).  From there you can split/parse the date and construct a DATE object.